# h2o SHAP predict contributions with MOJO

Tags: h2o, shap

as per release (https://www.h2o.ai/blog/h2o-release-3-26-yau/) it is said that SHAP values can be retrieved from MOJO as well. However in there is no function such as `h2o.mojo_predict_contributions` or equivalent ?

Once model is imported : `gbm_m=h2o.import_mojo('GBM_model_R.zip')`
and `h2o.predict_contributions(gbm_m,data)` is run ( note data is already a h2o data frame and h20 cluster is active ) . Below is the output :

[image]

There is another link (http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.2/latest-stable/doc/tutorials/shap_values.html) which doesn't give clear guidance on how to retrieve SHAP values in other than the sparking water h2o version. How can we extract SHAP values with a MOJO object directly without the need to spin off a cluster i.e. functions such as `h2o.mojo_predict_df`